# Compile Android app to iOS

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, compilation

Is it possible to create a new iOS app with exsisting sources?

I am working with xamarin in Visual-Studio. I've got a project, an app that runs on Android devices. But can I make a new project for an iOS app with those existing sources? I have a Macbook that I can use to do this. I also have a PC with windows 10 on it. So the hardware/software requierments shouldn't be a problem.

Getting to the point..

Is it possible to transform the project from an Android app to an iOS app without writing any code extra? And how can I accomplish this, any tutorials that I can watch/read?

The code language is C#. The programs that I am using are Visual studio and the xamarin extention.

I've read something about Platform Abstraction and Divergent Implementation on the xamarin ducomentation page, but this couldn't fully answer my question.

Comment: Well jesus turned water into wine. Makes absolute sense that you could convert an android app into an iOS app.

Comment: Yes I am aware that this can be accomplished, but how is my question.

Comment: My advice would be to create a Xamarin PCL and start porting your Android code into the PCL.  Once you have everything that you can get into the PCL  there, then you can create a new (separate) Xamarin iOS application.  Now the question becomes, do you want to have 2 separate UIs or do you want a shared UI?  You can start writing a new iOS specific UI or write a new Xamarin.Forms shared UI.  Once your UI is sorted, your PCL can be used to share code between the apps.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: NO.

Long answer:

There are a quite a few cross platform developing tools out there. Xamarin, like the one you are using, or Cordova. They simplifies the development by "A LOT" but you can't just convert one app to another without writing 0 code. Some of the libraries in one platform do not exist in the other. So, the long answer is that cross platform shortens the development cycle as you do not need to start from scratch on other platform, that does not mean it can completely convert.

P.S. Youtube is your friend, but the difficulty of the transformation solely depends on the scope of your project, as they vary a lot.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a small project converted into an iOS app?

Answer (score 3):

I second the other answers.

Furthermore, I'd like to propose to have a look at **[Flutter](https://flutter.io)**.

Flutter is based on [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org) language. The framework and your application get compiled from Dart to the Android and the iOS target platform.

Flutter is a product of Google and likely to get the base development environment for [Fuchsia](https://github.com/fuchsia-mirror), a new OS from Google.

My own experiments with [Xamarin](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/xamarin/) ended up kind of frustrating. The development was slow, several times problems with Xamarin itself or plugins made me stop the effort.

At the other side, I created an app with Flutter quite fast. While Dart and Futures might seem at first quite different compared to other concepts/languages, after some time things turn out to be very natural and well designed.

While Flutter originally was based on Material design, Google added an iOS theme using [CupertinoWidget](https://flutter.io/widgets/cupertino/).

A simply great feature is the enormous quick development turnaround time: The app under development very often adopts within just a second your source-code changes. Flutter/Dart hot reloads changed classes often instantly.

[Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) is a great and free IDE for Flutter development. Plugins enhance to IDE with Flutter development tasks.

Comment: I'd never recommend Flutter. Though it does the job. If you ever sat down to work with just beginning with the UI in flutter, its a night mare. Its worse than HTML 20yrs ago. Dart may be awesome, but you can't ask people to learn something that's illogical. The concepts are like beating ur head into the ground. I'd hate to become a copy paste programmer cz The flutter development team couldn't come up with a smarter/ logical way of making layouts. What a waste of an awesome product

Answer (score 0):

If you have android application written in Java you can use Migeran Analyzer to understand how much % of the code could be reused between android and iOS: https://analyzer.migeran.com/

Once you have the % you can use Intel Multi-OS Engine (free product) to create cross-platform application in Java: https://software.intel.com/en-us/multi-os-engine. It will have module with cross-platform shared code, android specific code module and iOS specific code module

[image]

Comment: Intel is a discontinued product. No option.